# Automatic tooltip

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a tooltip using javascript which is perfectly fine. But now I want that tooltip to run both automatically and manually. Now Automatic Means, You can check this link. https://www.adda247.com/.

This is my sample code , which one I am using.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="t1"]').tooltip(); });
    $(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="t2"]').tooltip(); });
    $(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="t3"]').tooltip(); });
    $(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="t4"]').tooltip(); });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
      <img src="img/s6.svg" height="400px" title="I became f!" data-toggle="t1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
      <img src="img/s7.svg" height="350px" title="I became g!" data-toggle="t4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
      <img src="img/s3.svg" height="300px" title="I became c!" data-toggle="t3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
      <img src="img/s4.svg" height="250px" title="I became c!" data-toggle="t2">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code is ok but can anybody tell me how to do it automatic too?

Comment: Please define "automatic". In the sample website, I see timed text balloons. Is that what you mean by automatic: have each tooltip appear and disappear at a specified number of seconds after the page has loaded?

Comment: yes @ Ruud Helderman

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle]').each(function(){
      $(this).tooltip();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `tooltip` on `document` rather than calling for each element .

```js
$( document ).tooltip();
```

```css
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="img/s6.svg" height="400px" title="I became f!" data-toggle="t1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="img/s7.svg" height="350px" title="I became g!" data-toggle="t4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="img/s3.svg" height="300px" title="I became c!" data-toggle="t3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3"><img src="img/s4.svg" height="250px" title="I became h!" data-toggle="t2"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My time i used jQuery is a while ago. But i think this should work like you want.

I checked the [API docs here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-enable)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get all toggle elements
    const toggleElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]');

    // initialize tooltips
    toggleElements.forEach(toggleElement => $(toggleElement).tooltip());

    let autoToggle = -1; // index of current toggle
    const intervalTime = 1000; // ms

    setInterval(() => {

        // disable last tooltip
        const oldToggle = toggleElements[autoToggle];
        if (oldToggle) {
            oldToggle.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseout'))
        }

        // enable next tooltip
        autoToggle = (autoToggle + 1) % toggleElements.length;
        const newToggle = toggleElements[autoToggle];
        newToggle.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover'))

    }, intervalTime);
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened with any solution guys

Comment: @errajkumar
Ok. I tried it to get it done using the provided functions. But this seams don't be possible.
Now i am triggering some custom events. This is not the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that tooltip to run automatically, you would need to set the trigger as manual, then you can trigger it on the page load. But if you want that tooltip to run both automatically and manually, do this:

```js
var tindex = 0;
var oldtindex = 0;

$( document ).ready( function() {
    var ttips = $('[data-toggle]');

    /*ttips.tooltip( { trigger: 'manual' } );*/

    setInterval(function(){
        ttips.eq( oldtindex ).tooltip().mouseout();
        ttips.eq( tindex ).tooltip().mouseover();
        oldtindex = tindex;
        tindex += 1;
        if ( tindex == ttips.length ) tindex = 0
    }, 2000 );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        <img src="https://static.adda247.com/images/ic-student-6.svg" height="400px" title="I became f!" data-toggle="t1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        <img src="https://static.adda247.com/images/ic-student-7.svg" height="350px" title="I became g!" data-toggle="t4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        <img src="https://static.adda247.com/images/ic-student-3.svg" height="300px" title="I became c!" data-toggle="t3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        <img src="https://static.adda247.com/images/ic-student-4.svg" height="250px" title="I became c!" data-toggle="t2">
    </div>
</div>
```